# SQL rand() dependent on another column?

Tags: sql, random

I have a table with the following format

```
id   cityname     user 
1    newyork        a
2    newyork        b
3    newyork        c
4    denver         d
5    colorodo       e
6    colorodo       e
```

I need to add a new column with name version which is randomly generated using rand() and it should have same values for similar cityname

```
id   cityname      user    version
1    newyork        a    1111111.11
2    newyork        b    1111111.11
3    newyork        c    1111111.11
4    denver         d    7845156.12
5    colorodo       e    8765589.12
6    colorodo       e    8765589.12
```

How can I achieve random values similar for a group.

Please help.

Comment: What RDBMS (SQL *Flavor*) do you use?

Comment: That sounds more like a hash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mitch mentioned, you can have it as `CHECKSUM`
you can make it as computed column, so that on `INSERT` or `UPDATE` it is computed automatically

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD version AS CHECKSUM(CityName)  PERSISTED
```

Comment: Thanks @Mitch, Rajesh. Very helpful for me.

I am using Abs in order to avoid negative values
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD version AS ABS(CHECKSUM(CityName)) PERSISTED

Comment: Also, is there any way to limit the number of digits to 6 using checksum?

Comment: @SQLGirl, checksum is a integer data type

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 or above, you can use the [`CHECKSUM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) function.  Keep in mind that you may get collisions with a 4 byte hash.

```
SELECT *, CHECKSUM(CityName) as Version
FROM Cities
```

For something a bit less likely to have a collision, you could use [`HASHBYTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx):

```
SELECT *, HASHBYTES('SHA1', CityName) as Version
FROM Cities
```

For MySQL, you can use any of the [encryption functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html), and take a substring:

```
SELECT *, LEFT(SHA1(CityName), 8) as Version
FROM Cities
```

or, just use the whole hash for some heavier collision protection.  Most other RDBMS have similar hash functions.